# What state is in the thread that the SynchronizationContext chooses that is not in the IAsyncStateMachine?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

When an `await` happens in an `async` method, an `IAsyncStateMachine` preserves "locals" and other necessary state. As far as I can tell, this includes method variables and static/instance variables that the method is using.

When the `await` happens, it also captures a `SynchronizationContext`, which determines when, where (on what thread), and in what order the method's re-entry (continuation) occurs. The thread that this context chooses for re-entry will include additional state that the continuation might use.

So not all of the "necessary state" goes into the state machine; some of it is in the thread that the `SynchronizationContext` chooses for the continuation.

Questions:

1. What state does the thread contain that the state machine does not?
2. What are the characteristics of state that goes into the thread versus state that goes into the state machine?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/12/asyncawait-faq/

Answer (score 4):

> When an await happens in an async method, the IAsyncStateMachine preserves "locals" and other necessary state. As far as I can tell, this includes method variables and static/instance variables that the method is using.

The state machine does indeed need to keep track of locals (which includes the parameters for the method).  It doesn't keep track of any instance variables or static variables.  You don't need to put them in the state machine for them to exist after the method ends; they'll continue to exist entirely on their own after the method ends.

> When the await happens, it also captures a SynchronizationContext, which determines when, where (on what thread), and in what order the method's re-entry (continuation) occurs.

While this is generally close enough to the truth for the purposes of casual references to it, and hence why many people tend to say this, this isn't quite right, and the subtleties are relevant to this particular question.

`SynchronizationContext` is just a class, and it has a `Post` and `Send` method in which the context is provided a method, and it executes that method in whatever "the context" means for that situation.  It can go about executing that delegate however it wants, and there are lots of ways that different contexts go about deciding how to execute that delegate.

For the synchronization context used by a windows forms or WPF application, it means running it in the UI thread's message loop.  For an ASP application it means scheduling a thread pool thread to run with a particular requests `HttpContext` set (while ensuring that no two are running at the same time, even though the same thread may not be used for all operations handling a request).  You can also write your own synchronization context that does whatever you want it to do.

> The thread that this context chooses for re-entry includes state that the method is uses.

Typically not.  The thread-specific state is primarily the data on the stack, which is primarily composed of method parameters and locals, but in the case of the `async` method the locals and method parameters were all hoisted to fields of the state machine.  While it's technically possible that the synchronization context is setting thread-static static fields (and this is in fact happening in the ASP case with `HttpContext.Current`) it's pretty unusual.  Any thread-specific state that is involved in this situation could only be code in the synchronization context, not anything inherent to the `async` keyword.

> What state does the thread contain that the state machine does not?

In the general case for an `async` method, none.  Any data that *would* normally be stored in thread-specific locations is moved to the state machine *so that it is no longer thread specific*.

> What are the characteristics of state that goes into the thread versus state that goes into the state machine?

All of it goes into the state machine if it would otherwise be specific to that thread.

Comment: "Any data that would normally be stored in thread-specific locations is moved to the state machine so that it is no longer thread specific." What are the implications for ASP.NET threads and user-interface threads? Does this mean that re-entry on an arbitrary thread will still work in those situations?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin For the purposes of the `async` method, yes.  The continuations quite often are run on a different thread.  (Also note that the synchronization context is also often not needed, so any method explicitly indicating it doesn't need to capture the context is likely running the continuation on another thread.)  If there is any thread-specific state that needs to be carried to the continuation, it would be the responsibility of a custom`SynchronizationContext` to handle it.

Comment: Apologies for my lack of understanding. These seem to contradict. First, "[the state machine] doesn't keep track of any instance variables or static variables." Second, "Any data that would normally be stored in thread-specific locations is moved to the state machine..." I am having trouble reconciling those two statements. Is it simply that normal static/instance variables are not thread local?

Comment: This .NET Fiddle indicates that normally thread-specific data is not moved to the state machine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/z54fWl That conflicts with your answer.

Comment: How does it contradict? Continuation **may** occur on the different thread, so local data isn't stored in state machine because it may continue the method on different thread.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Instance variables and static variable *are not thread specific*.  You can access any object instances and static variables from any thread.  It's all just data in the heap that is shared by all threads.  Like I said in the answer, the only thread-afine data that you really have is your locals on the stack, so that's all that needs to be moved to the state machine.

Comment: @VMAtm The continuation may occur on a different thread so local data *must* be stored in the state machine.  The state machine's data can be accessed from any thread, as it's just an object in the heap.  A local would normally be stored in the thread's stack, which, if it weren't moved to the state machine, would only exist on a single thread (and wouldn't allow that thread to return control back to the caller if the locals weren't moved, so they have to be).

Comment: @Servy I understand that. In a linked fiddler the `ThreadLocal` storage isn't stored in state machine, as it thread specific, so it isn't stored by the state machine.

Comment: @Servy Thank you. I now understand that normal static & instance variables live in the heap and are shared among threads. What remains unclear is this statement: "...data that would normally be stored in thread-specific locations is moved to the state machine..." The linked fiddle indicates that at least some thread-specific data is not moved to the state machine and remains thread specific.

Comment: @VMAtm I *specifically* addressed thread static variables in my answer already.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I *specifically* addressed thread static variables in my answer already.

Comment: @Servy Yes, you addressed thread-static variables, when you explained that the thread does not typically contain state that the method uses. You later wrote that "...data that would normally be stored in thread-specific locations is moved to the state machine..." That latter statement disagrees with what is happening to a `ThreadLocal<int>` in the referenced fiddle. Apologies for the confusion.